# Import() in React - fires error in the Chrome/Firefox extensions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have a working react app that runs on the `localhost`. I am using `import()` method to get some pictures dynamically. It is a loop that gets the URL of the pictures and stores it in the `state`. The code is very basic:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchPictures(items)
}

fetchPictures = (items) => {
  let imp = import(`path/whatever/items.path.png`)
    .then( image => {
       this.setState({
         images: [...images, image]
       })
    })
}
```

(I simplified it and left out the loop part for simplicity)

Very basic stuff and this works well on the `localhost`. However, what I am trying to build is a browser extension, and in there, it gets to the point where `import()` is and reports me an error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Array.map (<annonymus>)
at r (.png$:22)
...
```

I have put that `import()` in the `try-catch` and yes indeed, that is the problem.

Can someone tell me what might cause this issue? This is the same error for Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: you need don't need to use import() you just need to use import and path of it, another approch is use like  let imp = require('path/whatever/items.path.png')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Import like

```
import mainLogo from'path/whatever/items.path.png';
```

You can use require as well to render images like

```
fetchPictures = (items) => {
let imp = require('path/whatever/items.path.png')
.then( image => {
   this.setState({
     images: [...images, image]
   })
})
```

}

Comment: Works like a charm. But please, can you explain why I had to use `require()` when it clearly worked with `import()` in the `localhost`? Why are extensions that picky?

Comment: @VladimirKostov you can use import as well like import mainLogo from'path/whatever/items.path.png';